# Templating Python class level attributes to create generic rest serializers

Tags: python-3.x, templates, django-rest-framework

I'm using the Django Rest Framework and would like to serialize different types using the same format. The format being a list of all instances of a specific type as well a certain selected instance.

My problem is that I have to write a different serializer class for every type that I want to serialize. In C++ I'd solve this by giving the type and type serializer as a template argument. How can I do this in Python?

The generic Object I'd like to serialize:

```py
class OptionSelect(object):
    def __init__(self, options, selected):
        self.options = options
        self.selected = selected
```

What I currently need to serialize it:

```py
class TypeAOptionSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    options = TypeASerializer(many=True)
    selected = TypeASerializer()

class TypeBOptionSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    options = TypeBSerializer(many=True)
    selected = TypeBSerializer()

class TypeCOptionSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    options = TypeCSerializer(many=True)
    selected = TypeCSerializer()
```

Instead I'd like to create a Serializer like this:

```py
class OptionSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    options = serializer(many=True)
    selected = serializer()
    def __init__(self, serializer):
        self.serializer = serializer
        super().__init__()
```

Is there maybe a different approach that I should be taking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following:

```
def create_serializer(serializer):
  class MySerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    options = serializer(many=True)
    selected = serializer()
  return MySerializer

TypeAOptionSerializer = create_serializer(TypeASerializer)
TypeBOptionSerializer = create_serializer(TypeBSerializer)
TypeCOptionSerializer = create_serializer(TypeCSerializer)
```

This should be equivalent to your current approach with three separate classes.